# laravel 5.4 handler.php changing the default login for guest users

Tags: laravel

I have two tables: admins and users table.
When changing the default redirect in handler.php in laravel, I get this error:

[image]

My handler.php is as follows:

[image]

Comment: You have to create route */adminlogin*

Comment: you have to define /adminlogin route in your route file `https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-group-namespaces`